# What shared libraries are available on Heroku's Docker platform?

Tags: heroku, docker

I have a Haskell application I can successfully build and run in docker. It was, until recently, working fine in Heroku when deployed with `heroku docker:release`. However, now when I deploy it, I get segmentation faults when the binary is run in Heroku. This does not occur when I build and run the binary locally, either inside or outside of a Docker container.

I suspect this is due to dynamically linked libraries, which live outside the `/app` directory. Specifically, the executable links to the following libraries (the output of `ldd`):

`linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd1f5ec000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7119ecf000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7119cc7000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f7119ac3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f71198bf000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f711963f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7119336000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7119118000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7118f01000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7118b36000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055b23a73b000)`

Am I correct in thinking that this is an issue? Is there a good way to resolve this?

Comment: Heroku documents the binaries delivered as part of the Cedar stack [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-ubuntu-packages).